# How to find universities helping commercialization of research

Tags: united-states, industry

I have a PhD in computer science. I have done some successful applied projects. Now, I am looking for a postdoc position in the US. However, I prefer a university with more support for commercialization of projects.

As I tried to search, most universities have offices for university–industry liaisons, but I do not look for a collaboration with industry. I wish to find universities specifically have an office for helping student and staff to start their own business, i.e., if I complete an applied project, the university supports me to establish my company.

How can I find universities that actively have this service?

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. I edited your titular question and removed another question to have your question contain only one question, which is no [shopping question](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1736/revisiting-custom-close-reasons) and actually answerable by us (as opposed to the university).

Comment: It is fairly common for universities to _want_ to commericialize faculty research, and take a share. "Technology transfer" is a key-phrase to look for, and "Office of technology transfer" is the name of the office concerning such at my univ in the U.S.

Comment: @paulgarrett: That looks as if it should have been an answer

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, I don't really know that that phrase is typical in the U.S., so it'd be at best a very-partial answer... Also, it seems to be that faculty are expected to get external funding to _do_ the research that results in start-ups, etc., so the univ may not really "help"...

Answer (score 1):

All research universities in the United States have "technology transfer" or "commercialization" offices. They will help you patent your invention, license that patent to licensees, and/or help you set up your own company to commercialize the invention.

Of course, all of this is subject to an assessment that what you *think* is a commercializable idea is really worth the university's support.